# How do I reorder ggplot bar graph by year when I have multiple entries per year?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I haven't been able to find a solution that works for this yet. I have a data set similar to the simple example below. I want to make a bar (column) graph, plotting the serial_no on the x-axis and value on the y-axis, with the bars filled different colors depending on when each serial number is tested (one color for 2019, one color for 2020). When graphed, rather than having the serial numbers plotted alphabetically, I want all of the 2019 data graphed and then the 2020 data, so you would see three red bars followed by three blue bars. How do I arrange the data or the graph to make this happen? Thanks!

```
test_year <- c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020)
serial_no <- c("a3", "a6", "a4", "a2", "a1", "a5")
value <- c(5, 4.5, 6, 3, 3.5, 6)
df <- data.frame(test_year, serial_no, value)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x = serial_no, y = value, fill = factor(test_year))) +
                 geom_col(color = "black")
```

Comment: Try with `+ facet_wrap(~ test_year)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `facet_wrap` with `scales` as 'free_x'

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = serial_no, y = value, fill = factor(test_year))) +
                 geom_col(color = "black") + 
    facet_wrap(~ test_year, scales = 'free_x') + 
     theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

Comment: This is closer to what I was wanting, but not exactly.  Is there a way to have all of the bars plotted on one single graph? Not two graphs side by side. Using the facet wrap creates two side-by-side graphs (one for each year) that have empty spaces for the serial numbers that are not in that particular year. Is there a way to get the data all on just one graph?

Comment: @joerminer i updated by  adding `scales` argument

Comment: Thanks! I think that will work just fine for what I need, especially after I make a couple formatting changes for my use.